# Thermo-electric generator (TEG) harvesting using LTC3108

Tags: dc-dc-converter, energy-harvesting

I'm doing a project regarding thermal energy harvesting using TEG and an [LTC3108](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3108.pdf) boost converter.

I have constructed the circuit according to the datasheet of the LTC3108. I used a 1:100 surface-mount transformer from Mouser. I have connected the VS1 and VS2 to VAUX. I applied 0.33 V and 0.113 A to the input of the LTC3108, however, the output voltage only gets to 4.9 V. Is there any way to achieve a 5 V output?

[image]

[image]

Here schematic of the LTC 3108 ouputing a volatge of 3.3 V. To achieve 5V, the datasheet says to wire VS1 and VS2 to VAUX. I did VS1 and VS2 to VAUX but the ouput it's only 4.9V. I was trying to get the voltage to 5V.  Is there anyways to improve the circuits and gets the output to 5V?
Thank you in advance for your help!!!
[image]
[image]

Comment: 4.9 V is within spec for the nominally 5 V output of the LTC3108, see datasheet. It doesn't seem to be adjustable. Do you need exactly 5 V?

Comment: Yes, I need to achieve an output voltage of 5V. I'm a mechanical engineering major so i'm not very familiar with electronics. Is there anyways to improve the circuits and gets the output to 5V?

Comment: Is that digital meter calibrated?

Comment: Yes, the digital meter was calibrated.

Comment: Nice project! Look at LTC3105 which, according to spec sheet https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3105fb.pdf, can output up to 5.25 VDC.

Comment: @mingzhang My only guess is that  the high impedance of the multimeter might have something to do with it. Can you try to connect a 2000 ohm resistor(5V/2.5mA) and then measure the voltage again? Also, is the VOUT pin just connected to VOUT or also to VOUT2?

Answer (score 0):

As @orcdu states, 4.9V is within spec, see page 2 of the datasheet:
[image]

It would help if you posted a complete schematic.

You could find a similar IC with an adjustable output so you could calibrate it to 5V, or you could use the existing chip and use a adjustable boost converter, although it might be worth it to use an adjustable buck-boost converter (such as TI [TPS6380x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63805.pdf)) if the voltage sometimes goes over 5V.